# ttyUSBx reconnects until x>255 and stops

Tags: debian, udev, ttyusb

I've connected a prolific 2303 usb-serial adapter on to an armhf linux board
(Linux version 3.4.90+ (root@debian) (gcc version 4.7.1 (Debian 4.7.1-7) )

and for some reason the device keeps reconnecting. It could be a hardware issue or some issue with the hardware on the other end of the port. 
Every time it reconnects the udev kernel name increments by one. I've created a symlink for this device to cope with this. But after the actual device name reaches 255 it no longer works and only comes back to 0 after the device is rebooted.

EDIT:
Everytime it disconnects dmesg is showing, 
pl2303_read_int_callback - usb_submit_urb failed with result -19 (No Device) and it reconnects immediately

Comment: What's dmesg say?